# Accessing Parameters of Data Flowlet in Master Dataflow in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a dataflow "MasterDF" in which am using a DataFlowlet "Flowlet1" .
Iam using a source in the dataflowlet by passing parameterised dataset .

Now when i integrate that flowlet into my MasterDF and create a new pipeline > DataFlowActivity ( pointing MasterDF)
I cannot see parameters to pass to my data set .

How to solve this  [image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the flowlet parameter in the pipeline. You need to create a dataflow parameter and pass as an input to the flowlet parameter. In the ADF pipeline, you will get the options to pass input for dataflow parameter. I repro'd this with sample dataflow and pipeline. Below is the approach.

- Sample Flowlet is created with parameter `FL_par`. This flowlet is to add a table_name as a new column.
  [image]
- New Dataflow is created with parameter `DF_par`.

[image]

- Flowlet is added in this dataflow. Dataflow parameter is passed as input to flowlet parameter.

[image]

- Then in pipeline, input is given to dataflow parameter.

[image]

Thus, you can pass input to flowlet parameter through dataflow parameter.

Comment: My case is here , Source 1 has a parameterised dataset in flowlet .But you created parameter for flowlet itself. I need to access Dataset parameters ,not flowlet parameters.

Comment: What dataset do you use?Can you add the screenshot?

Comment: Added The Screenshots of my masterDF ,FLowlet and dataset in flowlet. So Now I need to pass parameters to that dataset via Dataflow activity pointing MasterDF

Comment: Are you not getting dataset parameters while adding flowlets in dataflow?

Comment: Nope ,Thats why am questioning here :(

Comment: In flowlet, I am not able to add dataset.  Refer this [img](https://i.imgur.com/D48HFqy.png). Only linked service option is there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251760/discussion-between-aswin-and-surya-teja532).